# What is the simplest way to generate domain specific url from application path..?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have application specific url like below

```
~/Default.aspx
~/Manage/Page.aspx
~/Manage/Account/Default.aspx
```

I really don't know what are these kind of paths actually called.

Now I need them to convert to domain specific complete URL. No `../` or `../../` like thing in the URL. I want URLs like

```
http://www.example.com/Default.aspx
http://www.example.com/Manage/Page.aspx
http://www.example.com/Manage/Account/Default.aspx
```

Currently I am doing this following way (assuming I have HttpRequest object)

```
Request.Url.Host + path.Substring(1);
```

Is there a more simplest way to achieve this..?

Comment: please, do some research before posting questions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390373/is-there-a-built-in-create-an-absolute-fully-qualified-url-from-a-relative-pat?rq=1

Comment: @saamorim did I forget mentioning that I need domain specific URL? The question u referred is about Absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have designed following static method from the Darin's solution. Now I can use it simply like `Utilities.GetAbsoluteURL("~/abc/xyz")`.

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static string GetAbsoluteURL(string relativePath)
    {
        return new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativePath)).AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string relative = "~/Manage/Account/Default.aspx";
string absoluteUrl = new Uri(Request.Url, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relative)).AbsoluteUri;
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to define your domain in app setting like

```
<add name="WebsiteURL" value="http://www.example.com/"/>
```

now in your c# code just wirte in your ASPX  like

```
<%=Config.WebsiteURL %>Default.aspx
<%=Config.WebsiteURL %>Manage/Page.aspx
```

Comment: +1 but a minor problem. I will have to change this each time when running site on locally and publishing it to server

Comment: you just need to change in web config no code change like in your live domain web.config give this <add name="WebsiteURL" value="live.example.com" /> got it ?

Comment: As I already said, I will have to change this. But there is no need to change anything in @Darin's solutions.